# Sip call Developing in android with secure data transfer

Tags: encryption, java, android

I would like to make an application similar to RedPhone on android. I took a look at SipDemo from `developer.android.com` and at the `android.net.sip` package.

My question is, when you make/receive a call, how can you get the audio stream to encrypt/decrypt it before is being sent/played back to the user? Is there a tutorial about this somewhere? I am aware that I need a sip account and real devices with android 2.3. I would like to get the AudioStream before it's sent (for encryption) and to receive the AudioStream before it gets played-back to the user(for decryption).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at countertap

http://sourceforge.net/projects/countertap/